# org-mode how to increase header level recusively in org file?

Tags: org-mode

How can I increase the level of headers recursively? example:

```
 * Top header
 ** Sub header
 *** Sub sub header
```

To :

```
** Top header
*** Sub Header
**** Sub sub header
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put point at the top header and try `<M-S-right>` (meta+shift+right arrow). This calls the command `org-shiftmetaright`, which moves the current heading and its subtree a level deeper.

Comment: It only work for 1 line at a time. How to do it for multi lines, like for a region?

Comment: If you want to move a region, use `<M-right>` or `org-metaright`, but be aware that this approach just demotes what is in the region so it may not behave as you expect if you have subtrees that extend outside the region.

Comment: yeah, it works once, then dismiss the region. but useful anyway

Comment: That's why it's called `transient-mark-mode`, but you can get the region highlighted again with `C-x C-x`. Do `C-h f transient-mark-mode` to learn more.